# How to import candidate-requisition with match operation in tcc?

Tags: tcc, taleo-connect-client

I want to import a candidate-requisition using match operation, but I don't know how, couldn't find match operation guidance. anyone have any idea?

Comment: The tag for TCC is reserved for the compiler ([Tiny C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Import > Candidate and select match option.
You will need three parameter the CSUser reference which is your Candidate ID, Requisition reference which is your Requisition ID and SendRMI if you want to send the matching details/application to Candidate (TRUE/FALSE).

Hope this helps you.